# Check the following function for differentiability and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Check the following function for differentiability and continuity

$$x\mapsto
\begin{cases}
   x^2 &\text{for }x<1;\\
   -x^2 &\text{for } x>2;\\
   1 & \text{for } x\in[1,2]
\end{cases}$$

## Solution

First I checked if this function is continuous:

- $\lim_{x\to1}1=1$ and $\lim_{x\uparrow 1}x^2=1$ produce the same result and $\implies$ continuous in the point $x=1$.
- $\lim_{x\to2}1=1$ and $\lim_{x\downarrow 2}-x^2=-4$ produce different values and function is not continuous in the point $x=2$

## Question

Now i need to check if it is differentiable in the $x=1$ (no need for $x=2$, because it is not continuous there). I tried: $\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\frac{1-1}{1-1}$ which is not a proper limit. Does it mean, that this function is continuous only in $x=1$ and is not differentiable in any of these 2 points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\uparrow 1} \frac {x^{2}-1} {x-1}=\lim_{x\uparrow 1}\lim (x+1)=2$. Since this is different from the right hand derivative (which is $0$) it follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: Could you please describe your solution a bit deeper? I would use lHospital rule to receive the same answer

Comment: I just used simple algebra: $x^{2}-1=(x-1)(x+1)$. No need for anything so sophisticated as L'Hopital's Rule.  @SavvaMirzoyan

Comment: oh, okay, double limit notation surprised me a little bit, @geetha290krm

Answer (score 1):

The limit is a tool that, in this case, provides us information about the function near a point. Your intuition is good, but you are not using the limit properly.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{f(x)-1}{x-1} &= \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}\\
&= \lim_{x\to 1^-} x+1 &&(x\neq1)
\end{align}
What I did in the last step was "cancel" $(x-1)$ both in the numerator and denominator. You can do that because, again, we are trying to understand what's happening in a "neighborhood" of 1.
In the same way, you could do that with the other derivative.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{f(x)-1}{x-1} &= \lim_{x\to 1^+} \frac{1-1}{x-1}\\
&= ?
\end{align}
What's the derivative from above?
If you draw this function, you'll see that there's and "edge" in x=1, and you could use the geometrically meaning of the real derivative to deduce that this function can't have a derivative there.